# Obtener parametro de un JS a un Page load

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Tengo esta función en javascript que está dentro de un `.aspx` que abre un `.aspx` llamado `Aplicaciones_Usuarios.aspx`

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#MasterContent_ui_rprApp_ui_hlkApp_0').click(function (e) {



                alert($(this).attr('text'));

                window.open("Aplicaciones_Usuarios.aspx?Url=" + $(this).attr('text'),"Aplicaciones");
            });


        });
```

El `text` lo obtiene de una etiqueta la cual es la siguiente:

```
<label ID="ui_hlkApp" runat="server" style="cursor:pointer;" text='<%# Eval("URL")%>'> <%# Eval("DESCRIPCION") %> </label>
```

Así que necesito obtener el parametro `text` de mi función js y pasarlo a  `Aplicaiones_Usuarios.aspx` porque ahí tengo un `iframe` donde el `src` tiene que tener lo que trae el parametro `text`.

```
<iframe id="iframe1" runat="server" src="Url" style="width:100% !important">

    </iframe>
```

Este es mi `Page load`:

```
public string Url;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        Url = Request.QueryString["Url"];

}
```

lo intenté de esa manera pero me manda un error.

Comment: probaste a utilizar un input oculto y enviarlo tramite post a la pagina que necesitas ?

Comment: ¿Podrías poner cuál es el error que te devuelve?